# How to increment a parent group number when the child window has incrementing values?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Spark SQL 3.2.0

Please see the [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gJYGuXZDqiy1pY18aqrpU/1) link for a simplified example of my dataset and desired outcome.

[image: query output]

In abstract, I have a dataset with a series of related events that can be grouped by their time order and event number. When ordering by time and event number, every time the event number resets to 1, you're looking at a new set of events.

I understand how to use `row_number()` or `dense_rank()` to increment `event_group_number` where `sub_event_number = 1`, but I'm uncertain how to make the rows where `sub_event_number > 1` take on the correct `event_group_number`.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
case 
    when sub_event_number = 1 and is_event_type
    then row_number() over (partition by context_id, event_id, sub_event_number order by is_event_type asc, start_time asc) - 1
    else null
end as event_group_number
```

I'd be grateful for any help, and I'm happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a cumulative conditional sum:

```sql
SELECT context_id,
       event_id,
       start_time,
       NULLIF(
          SUM(CASE WHEN sub_event_number = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(
                         PARTITION BY context_id, event_id 
                         ORDER BY is_event_type, start_time) - 1,
          0
       ) AS event_group_number
FROM   foobar
ORDER  BY context_id, event_id, is_event_type, start_time
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gJYGuXZDqiy1pY18aqrpU/5)